# Flutter Inkwell does not update right away

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to insert a widget / change height of a widget upon clicking a button. As demonstrated by the video, the `InkWell` does not update after calling `setState()`. This only happens with `Ink`, if changed to `Container` everything works fine. 

market.dart

```
class MarketPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MarketPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MarketPageState createState() => _MarketPageState();
}

class _MarketPageState extends State<MarketPage> {
  List<String> displayedList = [];
  bool isSearchActive = false;

  final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MarketList marketList = context.read<MarketList>();
    displayedList = marketList.markets.keys.toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Markets",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                isSearchActive == false
                    ? GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("hello");
                          setState(() {
                            isSearchActive = !isSearchActive;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                      )
                    : GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isSearchActive = !isSearchActive;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_right,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                      )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: isSearchActive == true ? 100 : 0,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.separated(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                );
              },
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: displayedList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                return MarketCard(
                    index, displayedList.length - 1, displayedList[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

market_card.dart

```
class MarketCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final int myIndex;
  final int lastIndex;
  final String name;

  MarketCard(this.myIndex, this.lastIndex, this.name);

  @override
  State<MarketCard> createState() => _MarketCardState();
}

class _MarketCardState extends State<MarketCard> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MarketList>(
      builder: (context, value, child) => InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => MarketDetailsPage(widget.name),
            ),
          );
        },
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: widget.myIndex == 0 ? Radius.circular(10) : Radius.circular(0),
          bottom: widget.myIndex == widget.lastIndex
              ? Radius.circular(10)
              : Radius.circular(0),
        ),
        child: card(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      ClipOval(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                          child:
                              Image.asset(value.markets[widget.name]!.iconURL),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 15),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            value.markets[widget.name]!.name,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Text(
                            "\$${value.markets[widget.name]!.currentPrice.toString()}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: value.markets[widget.name]!
                                            .priceChangePercent >
                                        0
                                    ? Colors.green
                                    : Colors.red),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try using key on item/  `CustomScrollView` / `NestedScrollView`

Comment: Will do. However, my guess is that the problem is with `Ink`, not `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GestureDetector` does not work well with `InkWell` for some reason. 
Replacing `GestureDetector` with `InkWell` solves the problem:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      isSearchActive = !isSearchActive;
    });
  },
  child: Icon(Icons.search),
),
```

### Edit

Trying to recreate the bug in a completely new codebase I came to the conclusion that it is not the problem of any single `Widget`. Something went wrong with the combination of those widgets. I am not sure what. `InkWell` seems to solve the problem for me, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Markets",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isSearchActive = !isSearchActive;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(isSearchActive ? Icons.arrow_right : Icons.search, size: 30),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          if (isSearchActive) Container(height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
          ListView.separated(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            primary: false,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return SizedBox(height: 15);
            },
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: displayedList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
              return MarketCard(index, displayedList.length - 1, displayedList[index]);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Added market_card.dart

Comment: Ok Let me check

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
MarketList marketList = context.read<MarketList>();

 setState(() {
           displayedList = marketList.markets.keys.toList();
         });
    print(displayedList.length)
}
```